# iOS app url scheme list

Tags: ios, url-scheme

Anybody know where I can get list of url scheme for this app's:

- Pandora
- Spotify
- Last.fm

I have found this link below, but I think this is not full list of url scheme:

1. http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/pandora
2. http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/last-fm

Thanks all for help!

Comment: also always check http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

Comment: Thank you, this is a really cool resource, but I have not found my app's there.

Answer (score 1):

The apple documentation states there is no comprehensive list, although  http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes seems to have an extensive list.

Comment: thanks for response, but do you check this link? I go to this link and don't see any info.

Comment: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes is the correct url. submitted an improvement, but until that gets reviewed...

Comment: This is not working so can you either update it or delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you’re looking for:

- Pandora: `pandorav2://`
- Spotify: `spotify://`
- Last.fm: `lastfm://`