# List of URL Scheme Mappings for Apple (Mac and/or iPhone)

Tags: ios, macos, url-scheme

I am trying to find more about custom URL mapping Schemes associated with a certain app. I checked a few SO discussions but have not been able to conclude. I have a few questions for URL Scheme Mapping,

1. Is there a way (like a certain command or a file that stores this info) to get a list of URL Schemes and the applications they map to on a given Apple  iPhone or Mac? (I am guessing the answer is no - based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/10951866/1165727 but I want to confirm since this answer is quite old).
2. Is running "strings" command on an app the only way to find out the URL schemes that are associated with the app? (This is based on the comments to this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5707825/1165727).
3. Is there a more complete list of URL Schemes than - http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

Comment: 1) No. 2) Look at the app's Info.plist file. 3) There is no definitive list.

Comment: @rmaddy - The point you mentioned about looking in the app's plist instead of running strings against the app has been helpful. Thanks!

Comment: As of 16 Dec 2019, the link in option 3 is broken.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On OS X, you can use:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -dump
```

That shows the dump of the Launch Services database, which includes URL schemes and their mappings to apps.

Comment: This doesn't cover everything though. The answer on this [post](https://superuser.com/a/548122/402911) offers two more alternatives to display more results. That command, for example, doesn't show that you can use `dict:\\` the dictionary app

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-line script which uses `Perl` to parse the data from the LaunchServices database, based on the answer by Ken Thomases.

```bash
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -dump | LC_ALL=C tr '\n' '\a' | perl -pe 's/(-{20}\aBundleClass)/\n\1/g' | perl -e 'sub trim {my $s = shift; $s =~ s/\a//g; $s =~ s/\"//g; $s =~ s/\{//g; $s =~ s/\}//g; $s =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; return $s}; sub trimCommas {my $s = shift; $s =~ s/,//g; return $s}; while ($line = <STDIN>) {if (index($line, "CFBundleURLTypes = ") != -1) {$urlTypesData = $line; $urlTypesData =~ s/^.*CFBundleURLTypes = .*?\((.*?)[^es] =.*$/\1/g; $urlTypesData =~ s/(^.*)\).*?$/\1/g; @urlTypes = split("}", $urlTypesData); if (trim($urlTypesData) ne "" && int(@urlTypes) > 1) {$name1 = $path = (split("CFBundleExecutable", $line))[0]; $name1 =~ s/.*name:(.*?)\a.*$/\1/g; $name2 = $line; $name2 =~ s/^.*CFBundleExecutable = (.*?)\;.*$/\1/g; $appName = ((index($name1, "(null)") == -1) ? trim($name1) : trim($name2)); $path =~ s/.*path:(.*?)\a.*$/\1/g; print $appName . "\f   " . "\033[38;5;173m(path: " . trim($path) . ")\033(B\033[m"; for ($i=0; $i<int(@urlTypes)-1; $i++) {$curUrlName = @urlTypes[$i]; if (index(@urlTypes[$i], "CFBundleURLName") != -1) {$curUrlName =~ s/^.*CFBundleURLName =(.*?);.*$/\1/} else {$curUrlName = "\e[3m[Blank]\e[0m"}; $schemesRaw = @urlTypes[$i]; $schemesRaw =~ s/^.*CFBundleURLSchemes =.*?\((.*?)\).*$/\1/g; @schemes = split(",", $schemesRaw); if (trimCommas(trim(@urlTypes[$i])) ne "") {print "\f\t" . trimCommas(trim($curUrlName)); for ($b=0; $b<int(@schemes); $b++) {print "\f\t\t" . trim(@schemes[$b])}}; print "\f"}}; print "\n"}}' | sort -uf | perl -pe 's/(\n)/\1\1\1/g; s/\f/\n/g'
```

Here is a few lines of the output:

[image: command output]